# A warning is display when i included a file in my template file, what could me the reason?

Tags: php, warnings

A warning is display when i included a file in my template file, what could me the reason?

> Warning: include_once()
>   [function.include-once]: URL
>   file-access is disabled in the server
>   configuration in
>   C:\wamp\www\ppm1.0\templates\threeColumnLayout.php
>   on line 24

Please suggest me some idea to rectify it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the filesystem path to the file, not the web path/uri. Or you could turn on `allow_url_include` (which also requires `allow_url_fopen` being on). but `allow_url_include` can be a security risk.